# matching columns of two different data frames in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with longitude and latitude values, and I would like to extract values from data frame #2 (say column `df2$C`, third column of the data frame #2) which value match columns of data frame 1... for example, data frame 1 has two columns (`lon`,`lat`), and data frame 2 has three columns (`lon`, `lat`, and some value `"C"`)... I want to add a third column to data frame 1, in which those values of `df2$C`   correspond to those values that are an exact match of BOTH columns in both data frames, something like `df1$lon == df2$lon` AND `df1$lat == df2$lat`... and in `lat`, `lon` pairs that doesn't match, I would like to add a `NA`, so that the third column (that I want to add to data. frame 1) has a length that is = `nrow(df1)`.
I tried the merge function, but I'm having troubles matching both columns of `df1` to those of `df2`.

Comment: `merge(...)` should work. You should show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setkey(setDT(df2), lat, lon)
df2[df1]
#   lat lon          C
#1:  58   1         NA
#2:  52  10         NA
#3:  54   7 -0.9094088
#4:  60   2         NA
#5:  50   3  1.4541841
#6:  56   9 -1.7771135
#7:  59   5         NA
#8:  55   8         NA
#9:  53   4         NA
#10: 57   6         NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(lat = c(58L, 52L, 54L, 60L, 50L, 56L, 59L, 55L, 
53L, 57L), lon = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("lat", 
"lon"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(lat = c(51L, 55L, 50L, 58L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 54L, 
 52L, 54L), lon = c(13L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 16L, 4L, 7L), 
 C = c(1.48642005012902, 1.53314455225747, 1.45418413640182, 
-0.874122129771392, -1.77711353745745, 0.128866710402714, 
-2.41118134931725, -1.78305563078752, -0.0173287724390305, 
-0.909408846416724)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since these are geocodes, one thing to watch out for is that the fields have to match exactly. So for instance if one dataset has lon/lat to 6 significant figures, and the other has lon/lat to 8 significant figures, you will get no matches (or very few). I wonder if this is why `merge(...)` isn't working for you. As shown below, it should work.

`merge(...)` should work, especially if both data frames have the same column names. Using the datasets from @akrun's answer:

```
merge(df1,df2, by=c("lon","lat"),all.x=TRUE)
#    lon lat          C
# 1    1  58         NA
# 2    2  60         NA
# 3    3  50  1.4541841
# 4    4  53         NA
# 5    5  59         NA
# 6    6  57         NA
# 7    7  54 -0.9094088
# 8    8  55         NA
# 9    9  56 -1.7771135
# 10  10  52         NA
```

If you don't specify the `by=...` argument, `merge(...)` will use *all common columns*, so in this case you could just write:

```
merge(df1,df2,all.x=TRUE)
```

You could also use `join(...)` is the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
join(df1,df2)
```

All of these options produce the same result, although the rows are in different order.

The data.table approach will be fastest, although without a really large dataset (>1e5 rows) you might not notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` for this. For example, with the data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(lat = c(58L, 52L, 54L, 60L, 50L, 56L, 59L, 55L, 
                              53L, 57L), lon = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("lat", 
                                                                                                       "lon"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(lat = c(51L, 55L, 50L, 58L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 54L, 
                              52L, 54L), lon = c(13L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 16L, 4L, 7L), 
                      C = c(1.48642005012902, 1.53314455225747, 1.45418413640182, 
                            -0.874122129771392, -1.77711353745745, 0.128866710402714, 
                            -2.41118134931725, -1.78305563078752, -0.0173287724390305, 
                            -0.909408846416724)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                               -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can create column C for df1 with

```
ifelse(df1[,'lat'] %in% df2[,'lat'] & df1[,'lon'] %in% df2[,'lon'],df2$C,NA)
```